# How to get the non matching value ONLY from the string and display into separate column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any VBA or formula to compare two paragraph and get the non matching values only(i.e not the entire string, only the difference value) from the paragraph and show into another cell in excel. Thanks in advance.

I tried with different formula but not able to get the exact difference values.
Formula's tried: =EXACT(H11,I11) and also tried with Conditionl Formatting.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Can you share examples of paragraphs and expected output. Naively, splitting the words into an array, deduping, and comparing feels like the right route, but it depends on what you mean by "non matching values". An example would help.

Comment: And what was your attempt? Are these 4 or 5 words or paragraphs of 50 or more?

Comment: If this is comparing two paragraphs where you want to surface words that are contained in only or the other (not both) you could use something like `=HSTACK(FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),ISNA(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),TEXTSPLIT(B1," "),0))),FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(B1," "),ISNA(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(B1," "),TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),0))))` Please clarify your requirements though so we can help more. In it's current form, the question is unclear.

Comment: This is likely a non-trivial task. Good luck.